# Testing component with modules I don't want to include

Tags: angular

In my component I'm trying to setup testing for, the template use some third party modules, such as ng2-bootstrap modules `alertModule` or `dropDownModule`.

They are irrelevant for the tests I'm trying to setup for this particular component. But if I don't include them, my test fails as the html fails to compile due to unknown directives and so on.

**Is there any way to create false "empty" modules to import, or even better don't care about them and make it Angular ignore third party modules** so I don't have to include them in the testBed (they won't be rendered on the template but I don't care here since my tests doesn't involve them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is some component that you don't need to declare you can either mock them or use the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` like suggested in the error and in the angular doc like this:

```
beforeEach( async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
declarations: [ AppComponent, RouterLinkStubDirective ],
schemas:      [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

look into https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#shallow-component-test for more info :)

Comment: What about services? I include a lot of services, especially vendors. For example: toastr service. Do I have to stub them all?

Comment: Well you can also use the real service if you want, but usually yes you stub them since is so easy to test a standAlone service ( or if is a vendor service is already tested ).But stub a service is even easier in the TestBed.configureTestingModule() config object into providers[] you can just do { provide: RealClassService useValue: stubbedVarPreviouslyDeclared }

Comment: If you're using Angular 5+, [shallow-render](https://github.com/getsaf/shallow-render) will automatically mock all the services and components/directives/pipes in your component's module. If you want to manually mock, see [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) and [ts-mocks](https://github.com/jjherscheid/ts-mocks)